# Android - Forecast.io icon label to custom font: weather-icons

Tags: android, fonts, icons, retrofit

I'm currently building a weather app using the forecast.io api.
They provide [custom font for Forecast.io](https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons), as well as for other apis such as Yahoo. I'm not sure about how to proceed to use their [API mapping](https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/api-list.html).

For instance, I receive "partly-cloudy-night" and this should render the icon.

I would welcome advices or clues on how to proceed.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the ttf file il your android project, and convert the css to xml string ressource.
I did it for Web Hosting hub glyph (a bit like font awesome but many more icons).

See https://github.com/neoteknic/whhg-to-android

I can reuse my convertion script an make a repo with these icons.

**Edit :** 
This is for you :
https://github.com/neoteknic/weather-icons-to-android

To use it (I prefer load only once the typeface and make it available globally) :

```
public class YourAppName extends Application {
    public static Typeface weatherIcons;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
YourAppName.weatherIcons= Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/weathericons-regular-webfont.ttf");
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

Then when you wanna use it :

```
TextView myicon=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.myicon);
myicon.setTypeface(YourAppName.weatherIcons);
myicon.setText(R.string.wi_day_snow_wind);
```